# My old voice memos don't sync via iTunes

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I have switched computer which I'm using to sync with my iPhone 3Gs. The problem is that all my old voice memos aren't added to my iTunes library, but they're still on the iPhone.

So I wonder how do fix so I can get all my voice memos to sync with iTunes?

Comment: I didn't think voice memos synced with iTunes.

Comment: i have the same problem all my old memos dont get synced into my itunes library

Comment: @henk, I haven't found an optimal solution for this. If you know one in the future please do post it here. As for now I have to manually copy all my voice memos manually and move them to the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Voice memo's didn't sync like music with older versions of iTunes. With any current version of iTunes it should sync properly.

I doubt that this question is still active, but for future problems I've added an answer.